# Converting epoc time in long milliseconds to timestamp for structured streaming sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read data stream following the below schema from kafka

```
val schema = StructType(
      List(
        StructField("timestamp",LongType, true),
        StructField("id",StringType,true),
        StructField("value",DoubleType,true),
      )
    )
```

***timestamp*** is coming as long milliseconds from epoc .

And I converted long value  to timestamp using the below method

```
val dfNew=df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String].select(from_json($"value",schema) as "record")
          .select($"record.id",$"record.value", col("record.timestamp").cast(TimestampType).as("timestamp"))
```

I want test following strcutured streaming query using window and watermarking

```
val output=dfNew.withWatermark("timestamp", "16 seconds").groupBy(window($"timestamp" , "10 seconds", "5 seconds"),$"uuid").count()
```

Its giving result , but in Window Clumn its is displaying a future time stamp

```
+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-----+
|window                                            |id                                |count|
+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-----+
|[50232-03-09 18:13:000.0, 50232-03-09 18:13:100.0]|11c7ebdb-8810-4a51-9d38-4099fd21862a|1    |
|[50232-03-09 17:49:400.0, 50232-03-09 17:49:500.0]|11c7ebdb-8810-4a51-9d38-4099fd21862a|1    |
|[50232-03-09 19:26:500.0, 50232-03-09 19:27:000.0]|58f86590-e27e-44d6-86d3-0905b126c9fd|1    |
|[50232-03-09 18:29:555.0, 50232-03-09 18:30:055.0]|11c7ebdb-8810-4a51-9d38-4099fd21862a|1    |
```

***50232-03-09 18:13:000.0*** ?

What could be the issue , I guess the conversion is wrong in kafka read stream query which I did 
***`col("record.timestamp").cast(TimestampType).as("timestamp"))`***

.But I couldn't find any place where this is tried.Every body is trying **from_unit_time()** , but that gives me zero result and also the resolution is seconds ,

any solutions ? Please...

Comment: Time zone, perhaps? Is your original timestamp long value in the time zone as where you're parsing it. Also, do you know the default TZ handling of that type cast?

Answer (score 3):

It simple. Spark represents interprets in *seconds* not milliseconds. So just divide the input by 1000:

```scala
Seq(1523013247000L).toDF.select(
    ($"value" / 1000).cast("timestamp"), // correct
    $"value".cast("timestamp")  // Your current code
).show

// +---------------------------------+--------------------+
// |CAST((value / 1000) AS TIMESTAMP)|               value|
// +---------------------------------+--------------------+
// |              2018-04-06 13:14:07|50232-05-15 05:16...|
// +---------------------------------+--------------------+
```